# application error django deployment heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and the deployment does not show me any error but when I try to load the website I get and `Application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.` I tried running `heroku logs --tail` as suggested and I get this traceback:

```
app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi        
app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load     
app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.wsgi'
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:13:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:13:14 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:13:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:13:14 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=2ec55eca-2585-4ac6-aee7-46468e80574b fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=d32ea5c2-101f-4779-9af6-0e83f067742b fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https        
app[api]: Starting process with command `bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` by user ankurcool.kumar@gmail.com
heroku[run.7249]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[run.7249]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.7249]: Starting process with command `bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`
heroku[run.7249]: Process exited with status 2
heroku[run.7249]: State changed from up to complete
app[api]: Starting process with command `bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python api/manage.py collectstatic --noinput` by user ankurcool.kumar@gmail.com
heroku[run.8052]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[run.8052]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.8052]: Starting process with command `bower install --config.interactive=false;grunt prep;python api/manage.py collectstatic --noinput`
heroku[run.8052]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[run.8052]: State changed from up to complete
app[api]: Remove DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC config vars by user ankurcool.kumar@gmail.com
app[api]: Release v16 created by user ankurcool.kumar@gmail.com
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn api.wsgi --log-file -`
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:40888 (4)
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_workerapp[web.1]: worker.init_process()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi        
app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load     
app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app     
app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.wsgi'
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_workerapp[web.1]: worker.init_process()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi        
app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load     
app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app     
app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.wsgi'
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
app[web.1]: [2021-05-01 17:19:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=c702fd57-86bb-465a-96db-22a56c14b595 fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=2cd4768f-ecbc-4caa-bf05-ae91d059db3a fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https        
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=227e3ea7-4405-4ce0-ad93-805887ca4250 fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/admin" host=teach-edison-assignment.herokuapp.com request_id=bf830d81-1697-4444-97a7-3d21072bba02 fwd="45.112.68.128" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried running collectstatic an I have tried installing djang-heroku packages as well. But it does not seem to work.

Here is my ProcFile:

```
web: gunicorn api.wsgi --log-file -
```

Here is my wsgi file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

this is my folder structure:

```
|api/
|-----|api/
|----------|__init__.py
|----------|asgi.py
|----------|wsgi.py
|----------|settings.py
|-----|otherapps/
|-----|anotherapp/
|-----|manage.py
|PipFile
|Procfile
|requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate. TL;DR, move everything in your `api/` directory up one level. Your inner `api/` directory, `otherapps/` directories, and `manage.py` should be beside your `Pipfile` (which should be called _`Pipfile`_, not `PipFile`), `Procfile`, and `requirements.txt`. Commit and redeploy.

Comment: Then decide if you want to use Pipenv (with a `Pipfile`) or pip (with `requirements.txt`) and delete the other one. Having both will just lead to confusion. `Pipfile` takes precedence over `requirements.txt` and `PipFile` is meaningless.